Will using these pins on the RPi Pico cause issues?
I'm wondering if any of the given pins are reserved for the RP2040's function. For context I'm making a line following robot for high school competition.
GPIO 0 - Start Button
GPIO 1 - Debug Pin
GPIO 2,3 - SDA SCL for 1.3in oled screen
GPIO 4-7 - controls DRV8835DSSR motor driver
GPIO 8-10 - Sets address for 74HC4051D Multiplexer
GPIO 26 - ADC for signal reading
If there are any issues in the design, please let me know.


You'll get better response if you include an image of your schematic in the question. We don't like Google drive links as the question is useless to others when the link dies.

@jsotola The optocouplers detects the line underneath the robot

Where is your 3.3V rail being made/converted? Also, how are you pulling up your I2C lines?

@Colin Thanks for pointing that out, Ill add resistors to the I2C lines. Im planning on using the pico's built in regulator for 3.3 volts but if you believe that's a problem, let me know.

The internal 3.3V regulator can only handle about 50mA as it's only purpose is to be a reference, not a power supply. The number of devices you're powering with this 3.3V rail is dangerous. I would recommend another voltage regulator for specifically your 3.3V rail to increase its current capacity, i.e. more than 50mA. Be mindful of your current draw and assume maximum current draw from all of your devices you are powering.
